# CQL partial key filter

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table in Cassandra where the key (now looking from a business perspective) is structure like this.
Example of a key + values:

```
Key (exists of 6 columns)             Date/value
A | B | C | D | E | F |    -> 2000-01 : 100, 2000-02 : 220, ....
A | B | C | D | X | F |    -> 2000-01 : 100, 2000-02 : 233, ....
A | B | C | D | Y | F |    -> 2000-01 : 111, 2000-02 : 210, ....
A | Z | C | D | E | F |    -> 2000-01 : 122, 2000-02 : 230, ....
```

Each key has a values per certain date or month (the amount of those date/value records per key is very low. Arround 200 for now). However, the amount of the keys is high.

From a business side, it's very unusal to query only for one specific key like A B C D E F. The user will apply only partial filtering like:

```
* * C D * *
```

In this case query should return all 6 records. He might also want to filter on the date/month, however, given the low amount of data this is a lower priority.

Since CQL does not allow partial table key filtering (beside the ALLOW FILTERING), I'm not sure how to structure my table. Any ideas? Or is this a case which does not fit well into Cassandra?

THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modeling with Cassandra, you'll need to create a table for each way you want to query your data.  So if you want to query by `D=some_val`, you'll need another table that can answer that query - that is, it'll have to have D as it's partition key.

Your other option is to do full table scans and manually filter, or to use something like Spark to work with your entire dataset.  I wrote a blog post a little while ago that shows what you can do with Spark & Cassandra.  http://rustyrazorblade.com/2015/07/cassandra-pyspark-dataframes-revisted/

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will have a look at Spark. However, I'm a maybe using the wrong technology for my problem? Is there anything in the Big Data world which would fit better? Relation DBs work but given the huge amount of data we have performance issues.

Comment: You can use materialized views (cassandra 3.0+).  There's nothing wrong with multiple views of the same table, it's the only way to get high performance in the big data world.  I did a video on RDBMS to Cassandra you might find useful to better understand the tradeoffs and architecture decisions: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds101-introduction-cassandra

Comment: FWIW, if you know your partition key and are willing to use Cassandra 3.4 when it comes out next month, you could probably use it's new secondary indexes.